Kernel panic for normal booting, but boots ok if chosen after pressing F11, or add nosmp=1 in kernel param
[updated: May 19, 2024]
I just encountered an extremely strange problem -
one of my Ubuntu rack server gives me a kernel panic error when booting the OS on the installed NVME drive (/dev/nvme0n1) as the primary boot in the BIOS, the error messages, including logs before kernel panic, are captured below



Strangely, if I press F11 during BIOS POST, and select the drive from the boot drive list, then it boots normally.
I also noticed that the above kernel panic happened after "x86 booting SMP configuration". if I add "nosmp=1" in the kernel parameter, then the system also boots, but only a single CPU is shown.
for some of the newer kernels, the panic information reads differently, for example, for 6.2 or 6.5, I see this instead, but have no way of capturing the full kernel panic log

I've tried many settings, see comments below, but none of them helped.
can someone suggest how to troubleshoot this? my server has AsRock TRX40 Creator mobo with AMD Threadripper 3990X with 256GB DDR4 memory.

You weren't specific with details (what did you actually install? as you only mention releases, not product/server or ISO details so we have kernel stack info).  I suspect you may have installed the system in one setting in firmware, then changed the firmware settings that make the system unbootable (as installed) then encounter the problem (ie. it boots when tried as installed) but you've given no specifics as to how installed, what installer etc due to lack of details (only releases are mentioned).  Did you run full RAMtests?  (from media; machine ones often only detect ram is present)

I have 10 identical nodes on this rack. All nodes have the same hardware and same identical cloned drives of Ubuntu 22.04 OS. they only differ by MAC address and domain names. All other 9 nodes are running fine. This node started failing in March, showing random segfault for random programs. suspect memory failure, ran memtest, found 1 memory error, see my previous post. In an attempt to fix this node, I tried many things, but non works - see below

I first tried 1) update bios to latest, 2)remove most memory, 3) installed and removed hwe kernels, some kernels start showing kernel panics, some others still show random segfault after boot. I then tried 4) clone /boot, /boot/efi partitions from an identical disk to the failed node, 5) use boot-repair from live-usb, and 6) use live-usb to reinstall Ubuntu (20.04). None of these works. For all kernels in my grub menu, either the boot hangs at "loading ramdisk", or kernel shows panic right after. Strangely, I notice that as long as I set the disk as the 2nd boot device, it boots normally.

I also plugged in another identically cloned NVME drive (/dev/nvme1n1) in one of the spare M2 slots, even I could boot /dev/nvme0n1 when setting nvme1n1 as 1st boot, and nvme0n1 as the 2nd boot, the booted system mount /boot and /boot/efi using those on /dev/nvme1n1, instead of /dev/nvme0n1. I realized that they have the same UUID. After manually setting different UUID for all partitions, I still could only boot /dev/nvme0n1 when I set it as the 2nd boot device. I used Linux for over 20 years and managed over 30 Linux boxes for my group, I've never feeling puzzled like this time.

I captured some additional kernal logs before the panic using a slowmo video. It seems related to SMP, but choosing the drive from F11 boot menu did not have any issue.

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu boots ok if choosing boot drive after pressing F11, otherwise hangs at "Loading initial ramdisk"

that was MY repost - aftering narrowing down the symptoms. the new post still don't have an answer yet.

I am closing this thread - after re-clone the disk to a working Ubuntu 22.04 system, kernel panic is gone. Now, the only symptom left is that the system can only be booted after manually pressing F11 during boot. it hangs at "Loading initial ramdisk ..." if not choosing from F11, regardless of Ubuntu version or kernel version.
I posted the updated problem in a new thread:
Ubuntu boots ok if choosing boot drive after pressing F11, otherwise hangs at "Loading initial ramdisk"
